# Twitter get followers/ids curosr not working

Tags: twitter

I am trying to get the complete list of follower IDs for a twitter user. This user has 170,000+ followers. I am using the code bird library. Here's the code:

```
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$cb->setReturnFormat(CODEBIRD_RETURNFORMAT_ARRAY);
$next_cursor = -1;

while ($next_cursor) {  
    $results = $cb->followers_ids("screen_name=some_tw_name","count=5000","cursor=$next_cursor");
    $next_cursor = $results['next_cursor_str'];
}
```

The first call returns 5000 IDs, as it's supposed to. Subsequent calls (through the while loop) return 5000 IDs, but they are almost all the same as the previous call (each new call I get 1 to about 10 news IDs, with the remainder the same as before).

Anyone else run into this issue? resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not really combining the results from each of the requests. so you could do something like this:

```
function getFollowers(){
    $next_cursor = -1; 
    $output = array();
    while ($next_cursor) {  
        $results = $cb->followers_ids(array("screen_name"=>"some_tw_name","count"=>5000,"cursor"=>$next_cursor));
        if(!isset($results['errors'])){
            foreach($results['ids'] as $id){
                $output[]=$id;
                }
            }
        $next_cursor = $results['next_cursor_str'];
        }
    return $output;
    }
```

Note: I also changed the argument notation to an array as opposed to strings.

Comment: You realize that the value for next_cursor is supplied by Twitter, right? as in it's supplied in the API call return as next_cursor_str. If you "combine" the results, all you get is an arbitrary number that's not an accurate representation of where Twitter decides your next cursor should be. You should read the Twitter API docs.

Comment: I didn't mean to combine your cursor.. I said you need to combine the results, your code doesn't do that; it creates several disparate arrays. I don't have a problem creating a full list of followers using that code.

Comment: Yes, my code does not combine the results. That has no bearing whatsoever on why when I dump $results, I should get a different set of IDs with every loop with a different cursor. These two issues are separate. Combining my results is a bad coding practice, as it becomes a memory hog. What's missing is the function where I process $results with every loop, and is not necessary for my question.